# Sub menu taxonomies with Wordpress in a Primary menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a sub-menu to my 'Primary' Menu for a Wordpress site.

See screenshot of the design here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwOpo.jpg[image]

How could I go about adding the sub menu with these custom taxonomies, I know I can use get_terms() for the taxonomies but I am not sure of how i'd implement this in WP Admin.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Solved by making static menu with sub calls to terms.